# difference between possible std::forward implementations

Tags: c++

I saw 3 implementation directions for `std::forward`.

In order to test them I wrote the flowing test:

```
void test(int&&){ std::cout <<"refref\n";}
void test(int&){ std::cout <<"ref\n";}

template<class T>
void foo(T&& t){
     test(fwd<T>(t));

int main (){
   auto v = 5;
   foo(5);
   foo(v);
   foo(std::move(v));
}
```

The first and simplest is:

```
template <typename T>
T&& fwd(T& t) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

From what I can see the main issue here is that `T` can be deduced.
In such a case, it will always return Rvalue reference (`T` will be deduced to `T` (and never to `T&`), and there will be no reference collapsing)

in order to resolve this, we can add identity class:

```
template<typename T>
struct identity{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
T&& fwd( typename identity<T>::type t) {
   return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

However, I see that the standard dictates:

```
template <typename T>
T&& fwd( typename remove_reference<T>::type t) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: you have a copy-paste error (last two fwds are identical).  And a typo `Cast` in `static_Cast`.  I can read your mind but my mind reading is not as good as my C++, so I'd rather you fix the error yourself.

Comment: You just said the first would always return a rvalue reference? You also have random uppercase/symbols all over the place.

Comment: You'll need your function to accept a **forwarding reference** (sometimes called a "universal reference") for proper forwarding to work.

Comment: @Yakk And here I thought you are a professional crystal baller. Disappointment

Comment: @yakk, updated the last version, to use remove_reference. sorry for the copy-past error, and for the typo...

Comment: Nope, std::forward is not defined like that. It's `constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept`. Count the `&`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
T&& fwd( typename remove_reference<T>::type t) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

this is not the correct implementation of `std::forward`.

```
template <typename T>
T&& fwd( typename remove_reference<T>::type& t) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
template <typename T>
T&& fwd( typename remove_reference<T>::type&& t) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

these two are.

Yours takes the `t` by value; `std::forward` always takes by rvalue or lvalue reference.  (I omitted [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)'s `constexpr`, as that isn't important right now).

I'll compare yours:

```
template <typename T>
T&& fwd( typename identity<T>::type t) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

to the correct code.

Yours is wrong in two ways. First, it takes by value if you pass in a non-reference type:

```
struct foo {
  foo(foo&&)=default;
  foo(foo const&)=delete;
};

foo f1;
auto f2 = fwd<foo>(f1);
```

this fails to compile in your version, as `fwd<foo>` takes a `foo` by value, so in calling it it tries to copy `f1` into its argument.

We can fix this to some extent:

```
template <typename T>
T&& fwd( typename identity<T>::type&& t) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

but now, when you pass in `T=foo` you are forced to pass it an rvalue.  That isn't good.  So now we add another overload:

```
template <typename T>
T&& fwd( typename identity<T>::type& t) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

and when we pass `T=foo` we can take *either* an rvalue or an lvalue argument.  So far so good.  But what happens when we pass `T=foo&`?  Well, then the first overload becomes `foo& &&` which turns into `foo&`, and we are blocked from taking rvalues and then using forward to cast them to lvalues.

```
auto f3 = fwd<foo&>( foo{} );
```

the above is legal for `std::forward`, but not for your `fwd`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Do I understand correctly that remove_reference<T>::type&  and identity<T>::type& are interchangeable in this context??

Comment: @user9571380 Sounds reasonable.